# Difference Between Publisher Subscriber Model and Client Service Model

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What exactly is the difference between the two? From what I gather, messages in a publisher/subscriber are only sent one way from publisher to subscriber but in the client/service model, messages can go both ways. Is this correct?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/237672/difference-between-publisher-subscriber-model-and-client-service-model/) by [Syngerical](https://answers.ros.org/users/27138/syngerical/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-06-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is a bit more to publish/subscribe and client/*server* (or remote-procedure-call) than just the direction in which messages flow.

A good paper that discusses the main benefits of the publish/subscribe communication *style* and compares it to traditional remote procedure call is [The Many Faces of Publish/Subscribe](http://www.cs.ru.nl/%7Epieter/oss/manyfaces.pdf) by Patrick Eugster et al.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-06-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2